# Set umask in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I'd like to change my umask on my Mac. Before Yosemite I used the file `/etc/launchd-user.conf` file and just added the command `umask 0077`.

The aim is to get proper file permissions when saving a file in any every GUI program e.g. Finder, Notes & Firefox. To add the umask in `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` don't solve the problem.

In Yosemite the files `/etc/launchd.conf` and `/etc/launchd-user.conf` aren't executed anymore. The `man launchctl`says:

> The /etc/launchd.conf file is no longer consulted for subcommands to run during early boot time; this functionality was removed for security considerations.

I tried different example using LaunchAgents. Which this I'm able to set environment variables (e.g. `ENVIRONMENT_RC`) but the umask is never set.

/etc/environment

```
#!/bin/sh

umask 0077

launchctl setenv ENVIRONMENT_RC "yes"     # Debugging
```

/Library/LaunchAgents/environment.user.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>environment.user</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/bin/sh</string>
            <string>/etc/environment</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/etc/environment</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any ideas to set the umask in OS X Yosemite?

Thanks,
Reto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a final solution in OS X Yosemite 10.10.3:

instead of /etc/launchctl-user.conf use:
`launchctl config user umask 002` 
(example umask for setting 775 permissions)

instead of system wide /etc/launchctl.conf use:
`launchctl config system umask 002` 
(example umask for setting 775 permissions)

Apple published the how-to for "Yosemite umask problem" update five days ago (Apr 8, 2015) here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201684

Comment: Hi Petr, you are my hero of the day. Thank you very much for the hint! Regards, Reto

Answer (score 0):

**Status report**

Unfortunately there was no valid answer so far about this question. But never mind. The Apple Support have not a clue, either. They said the umask is not set anylonger in OS X. What a shame!

The `umask` subcommand from `launchctl` is gone but there is still a possibility to set the key word "Umask" in .plist files (e.g. used in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.configd.plist):

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
...
    <key>Umask</key>
    <integer>18</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My plan is to add this parameter to the LaunchAgent file which starts the first process in the user's context.

I keep you informed...

Regards,
Reto